# Code wordpress Plugin to save to Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Whats the best way to create a wordpress plugin. I have started out learning to make plugins and i want to make a plugin to calculate 2 numbrs and save to a mysql database.

since i didnt know OOP in PHP i decided to code what i know.

my code looks like this only my instructor wants me to do something Awesome.. better than what i coded earlier.

**Edit**

Now i am trying to make this add and then send to the database.

Code looks like this now

```
  <?php

/*
  Plugin Name: Addition DB Plugin
  Description: Plugin to Add to Database and call back from database
  Author: James Ibrahimov
*/

global $wpdb;

function add2numbersandsavetoDB()
{
    $num1 = '5';
    $num2 = '11';

    $ans = $num1 + $num2;

    $wpdb -> insert('answer',array(
        'id' => 'id',
        'ans'=> $ans
    ),
   array('%d','%s') );
}

add_action('main_menu', 'add2numbersandsavetoDB');

function displayDatafromDB()
{
    $results = $wpdb-> get_results("select * from answer");
    foreach($results as $result){

        echo $result-> id;
        echo $result-> ans;
    }

}

add_action('main_menu','displayDatafromDB');
?>
```

Comment: What  is your issue/question? Does your code work? I mean, _"my instructor wants me to do something Awesome.. better than what i coded earlier"_ isn't particular helpful and doesn't tell us anything about anything. Shouldn't your instructor be the one that helps you with it?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson My instructor wants me not to use this method to save to a mysql database after Adding using wordpress plugins, he wants me to code something and send to a database after addition using wordpress plugins . he wants to see how far i can go first before he helps out.

Comment: Sorry, but that comment doesn't clarify anything. Just saying that you want to do it differently or "Awesome" isn't good enough. We're not here to refactor your code for you. A tip, check out Wordpress documentation about doing database calls and use their existing classes instead. Here's the link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb - Learning OOP would be another good start.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson where can i get materials for OOP

Comment: Just google something like "learn php oop" and find some tutorials and guides that you can read and do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using php for inserting dta into database. 
use wordpress functions to insert data into data.

```
change
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'wordpress_tut';
to
 global $wpdb; 

use this to insert your data
$wpdb->insert( 
    'table_name', 
    array( 
        'column1' => 'value1', 
        'column2' => 123 
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s', 
        '%d' 
    ) 
);
```

for more information how to insert or get data [click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Comment: thanks prince, i figured.Now i am trying to figure how to send it to the database... like how to i trigger it.

Comment: welcome James, click on the link, there you can get more information.